# Suddenly cannot build my nativescript IOS app

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-cli

Not sure what happened but I cannot build my NativeScript app for IOS any more. I was just testing out the EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-barcodescanner plugin. It built and the app scanned a QR code. I'm pretty sure my code wasn't correct as I was just trying a first test run, but afterward, when I try to run ios --device to my iphone I get the following string of warnings ending in the error shown at the end. Would love to get an idea what's going on if anyone knows. Here is the full console output (personal data changed obviously):

```
tns run ios --device <device id here>
Searching for devices...
Your application will be deployed only on the device specified by the provided index or identifier.
Preparing project...
Project successfully prepared (iOS)
Building project...
Xcode 8 requires a team id to be specified when building for device.
You can specify the team id by setting the DEVELOPMENT_TEAM setting in build.xcconfig file located in App_Resources folder of your app, or by using the --teamId option when calling run, debug or livesync commands.
Found and using the following development team installed on your system: Joe Bloggs (12345ABCDEF)
Xcode build...
2018-02-27 13:01:17.309 xcodebuild[2676:424417]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 9f22ffea744c3f2cbaaa0171cf210fa63af97e72 was NULL
=== BUILD TARGET projectname OF PROJECT projectname WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/AKLQJDH2Y6SE/UIKit-2LM3EQU7VVY4O.pcm: No such file or directory
note: Linking a static library that was built with -gmodules, but the module cache was not found.  Redistributable static libraries should never be built with module debugging enabled.  The debug experience will be degraded due to incomplete debug information.
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/AKLQJDH2Y6SE/Darwin-MI6WZSG1PNOM.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/AKLQJDH2Y6SE/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/AKLQJDH2Y6SE/Dispatch-12O7S7HHQXK9N.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/AKLQJDH2Y6SE/ObjectiveC-2CD0WTQVXITO7.pcm: No such file or directory
Xcode build...
2018-02-27 13:01:31.527 xcodebuild[2771:426042]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 9f22ffea744c3f2cbaaa0171cf210fa63af97e72 was NULL
=== BUILD TARGET projectname OF PROJECT projectname WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2BFR9L55Q8TX5/UIKit-2LM3EQU7VVY4O.pcm: No such file or directory
note: Linking a static library that was built with -gmodules, but the module cache was not found.  Redistributable static libraries should never be built with module debugging enabled.  The debug experience will be degraded due to incomplete debug information.
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2BFR9L55Q8TX5/Darwin-MI6WZSG1PNOM.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2BFR9L55Q8TX5/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2BFR9L55Q8TX5/Dispatch-12O7S7HHQXK9N.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2BFR9L55Q8TX5/ObjectiveC-2CD0WTQVXITO7.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/AKLQJDH2Y6SE/UIKit-2LM3EQU7VVY4O.pcm: No such file or directory
note: Linking a static library that was built with -gmodules, but the module cache was not found.  Redistributable static libraries should never be built with module debugging enabled.  The debug experience will be degraded due to incomplete debug information.
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/AKLQJDH2Y6SE/Darwin-MI6WZSG1PNOM.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/AKLQJDH2Y6SE/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/AKLQJDH2Y6SE/Dispatch-12O7S7HHQXK9N.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
warning: /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/AKLQJDH2Y6SE/ObjectiveC-2CD0WTQVXITO7.pcm: No such file or directory
Xcode build...
2018-02-27 13:01:49.139 xcodebuild[2894:427429] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/px/nqp0zv8x6851gnsbb0452gd40000gn/T/projectname_2018-02-27_13-01-49.138.xcdistributionlogs'.
Exported projectname.xcarchive to: /Users/myusername/mobile/nativescript/projectname/platforms/ios/build/device
Project successfully built.
Unable to apply changes on device: 9f22ffea744c3f2cbaaa0171cf210fa63af97e72. Error is: Could not start service com.apple.mobile.installation_proxy.
```

Comment: Deploying on a real iOS device requires development provisioning profile (for the app) and development certificate. You can run `tns run ios --provision` to see the available provisions and then run `tns run ios --provision <app-rpovision-here>`  .. or you can use the wildcard team ID in DEVELOPMENT_TEAM in your `build.xcconfig`

Comment: Use the SideKick step-by-step articles if in trouble https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/code-signing/code-signing-for-ios/ios-developer-program

Comment: Thanks Nick. I was trying to publish through XCode and was setting up provisioning profile for the app so I could try and upload it to testflight. I think something must have gone wrong during that process. You comment looks like it's leading in the right direction, thanks

Comment: For publishing you should sign the app with distribution profile (not the development one)

Comment: Still not working:
- Created a new cert using a new csr and downloaded the cer
- Created an app id with a new id com.mydomain.*
- Created a development provisioning profile for the app using the app id above
- Created a new app (using NS sidekick), new cert and mobileprovisioning file
- I build the app with errors as above, but it builds
- I try to run the app on my device (it's registered on my apple dev account), I get: [18-03-01 22:42:47.689] (Info) Stopped LiveSync on <my device id> for /Users/myUserName/mobile/App name.

Should I be using ad hoc or some other provisioning profile?

Comment: App will build perfectly if I bring it into xcode

Comment: @NickIliev https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262183/assertion-failure-and-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-in-nativescript Can u help me on this?